# R coordinates function - specify two pairs of spatial coordinates

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I wish to promote to spatial data but it has two pairs of co-ordinates in it - journey origin Ordnance Survey grid references and journey destination Ordnance Survey grid references .

So I want to promote the data frame to spatial then re-project to WGS84. I can do this with a single pair of co-ordinates:

```
# promote data frame to spatial
coordinates(myvar) = ~Easting + Northing
# give it the OS projection
proj4string(myvar)=CRS("+init=epsg:27700")
# convert projection to WGS84 as used by osm
myvar.WGS84 <- spTransform(myvar, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

But how can I do it with two pairs?

Edit - I have achieved it by splitting the data frame and rejoining as per the code below, but there surely must be a more efficient and elegant way of doing it:

```
#create separate object for destination and Dest grid refs
 destgridrefs <- mydata %>% select(-Origin_Easting, -Origin_Northing)
 origingridrefs <-  mydata %>% select(rowID, Origin_Easting, Origin_Northing)
#rename the columns
 destgridrefs <- destgridrefs %>% rename(lat=Dest_Easting, long=Dest_Northing)
 origingridrefs <- origingridrefs %>% rename(lat=Origin_Easting, long=Origin_Northing)
# make data frame
 destgridrefs <- as.data.frame(destgridrefs)
 origingridrefs <- as.data.frame(na.omit(origingridrefs))
# promote data frame to spatial
 coordinates(destgridrefs) = ~lat+long
 coordinates(origingridrefs) = ~lat+long
# give them the OS projection
 proj4string(destgridrefs)=CRS("+init=epsg:27700")
 proj4string(origingridrefs)=CRS("+init=epsg:27700")
# convert projection to WGS84
 destgridrefs.WGS84 <- spTransform(destgridrefs, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
 origingridrefs.WGS84 <- spTransform(origingridrefs, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
# then convert spatial points to a data frame so they can be used by ggplot
 destgridrefs.WGS84.df <- as.data.frame(destgridrefs.WGS84)
 origingridrefs.WGS84.df <- as.data.frame(origingridrefs.WGS84)
# join them together                                                    
 allgridrefs <- inner_join(destgridrefs.WGS84.df, origingridrefs.WGS84.df, by="rowID")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Your explanation is quite unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the coordinate pairs in a `SpatialLines` object. Here, one line is a origin destination pair. The following code is an example from the [`sp` package documentation of `SpatialLines`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/rbind.SpatialLines):

```
# from the sp vignette:
l1 = cbind(c(1,2,3),c(3,2,2))
l1a = cbind(l1[,1]+.05,l1[,2]+.05)
l2 = cbind(c(1,2,3),c(1,1.5,1))
Sl1 = Line(l1)
Sl1a = Line(l1a)
Sl2 = Line(l2)
S1 = Lines(list(Sl1, Sl1a), ID="a")
S2 = Lines(list(Sl2), ID="b")
Sl = SpatialLines(list(S1,S2))
summary(Sl)
plot(Sl, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately I couldn't follow your method to get what I needed, I will try soem more but in the meantime as edited in my OP I have split the dataframe and then rejoined it.